# How to read Object?

Tags: javascript

Say i have object like

```
var a = {"user":
                {'average':
                           {'score':4
                           }
                }
         }
```

How can I read object value using its keys

Say I have user Object with me and have key "average.score" can I get the value directly?

```
a.user["average.score"];
//Coming as undefined
a.user["average"]["score"]
// Working as expected  : 4
```

I have the key of "average.score" all together with me want to get the value of score how can I do it directly without splitting the key.

Comment: Use `a.user.average.score`

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj key is coming in parameter that can't be done

Comment: any key that is dynamic can be put in square brackets. Suppose `average` key is dynamic. Then, use `a.user[average].score`

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj "average.score is entire key"

Comment: Which keys are you getting in parameters? I mean what keys are fixed and which ones are dynamic?

Comment: @Andreas yes that stack solved my case thanks